# Why GetElementById returns null?

Tags: c#, xmldocument

Hello I've got an xml file with some text i want to display randomly, but the elem always returns `null`. I know this question has been answered a lot of times, but all those answers didn't solve my problem.

```
public void Welcome()
{

    string value = new Random().Next(0,3).ToString();
    Debug.WriteLine(value);
    XmlElement elem = LoadFiles.welcome.GetElementById("i"+value);

    Debug.WriteLine(elem.InnerText);

}
```

Here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE Data [
<!ELEMENT tree ANY>
<!ELEMENT Welcome ANY>
<!ATTLIST wel id ID #REQUIRED>
]>

<Data>
<Welcome>
    <wel id="i0">
        red
    </wel>
    <wel id="i1">
        blue
    </wel>
    <wel id="i2">
        yellow
    </wel>
</Welcome>
</Data>
```

Maybe the problem is in the DTD, I don't really know how is has to be exactly. The [documentation for `GetElementById`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx) suggests the above should work.

Here's a full test case ([live copy on ideone](https://ideone.com/r0lkQy)):

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
        <!DOCTYPE Data [
        <!ELEMENT tree ANY>
        <!ELEMENT Welcome ANY>
        <!ATTLIST wel id ID #REQUIRED>
        ]>
        <Data>
        <Welcome>
            <wel id=""i0"">
                red
            </wel>
            <wel id=""i1"">
                blue
            </wel>
            <wel id=""i2"">
                yellow
            </wel>
        </Welcome>
        </Data>");
        var elem = doc.GetElementById("i1");
        Console.WriteLine(elem == null ? "It's null" : elem.InnerText);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I know this question has been answered a lot of times, but all those answers didn't solve my problem."* List the questions you've looked at, and be specific about what it was about them the didn't solve the problem for you.

Comment: Change `<!ELEMENT tree ANY>`  to `<!ELEMENT wel ANY>` That is all.